# Why does SciPy return negative p-values for extremely small p-values with the Fisher-exact test?

Tags: python, r, statistics, scipy

I've noticed that the Fisher-exact test in SciPy returns a negative p-value if the p-value is extrememly small:

```
>>> import scipy as sp
>>> import scipy.stats
>>> x = [[48,60],[3088,17134]]
>>> sp.stats.fisher_exact(x)
(4.4388601036269426, -1.5673906617053035e-11)
```

In R, using the same 2x2 contingency table:

```
> a = matrix(c(48,60,3088,17134), nrow=2)
> fisher.test(a)
p-value = 6.409e-13
```

My question is 1) why does SciPy return a negative p-value? 2) how can I use SciPy to generate the correct p-value?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fisher's exact test uses the hypergeometric distribution.

The version of scipy you are using uses an implementation of the hypergeometric distribution that is not very precise. This is a [known problem](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1926) and has been fixed in the scipy repository.